# Installing Dynamics CRM on separate server

Tags: windows-sbs, microsoft-dynamics-crm

For our domain, AD and Exchange run on a Win2003 SBS. I dimly remember that SBS does *not* allow certain services to run on a different (or multiple) servers in the domain, but I can't dig up anything.

We are currently evaluating MS Dynamics CRM, but it seems the SBS server can not really carry that load.

We consider replaceing the current secondary server (W2K3 Std, mostly fileserver and a few client/server apps) in the near future, and I wonder if we could run CRM on that, or if there are any restrictions to that - i.e.

- Are there any limitations to servers running "besides" a SBS that would affect MS Dynamics?
- can MS CRM run on a different server than Exchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To what Moo said, yes it is advised to setup CRM on it's own server. It does take up a bit of "juice" running. Also don't forget to install the router part of it on the server, that will take off some of the load from the client making it so that the server sends CRM e-mails and not the clients.

In addition, we just found out that the job that runs to clean up the CRM database to actually delete the deleted items is scheduled to run at the time the server is installed, you should probably take that into the capacity planning as well.

Answer (score 1):

As to your second point, MS CRM can and will run perfectly fine on a different server to Microsoft Exchange, and is actually recommended (you cannot install the CRM Outlook client on a system with Microsoft Exchange or the Exchange Tools installed however).

Answer (score 1):

We run CRM 4.0 on 2008 server standard virtual machine no problems.  It's good.

Make sure you have plenty of RAM in the server.  Guest system has 3Gb allocated 50% used for 15 connected users, jumps up when reports are being run.

You will need to run IIS and SQL too, these can be on the same server as CRM.